# How to show NLS conserves the energy?

Tags: analysis, reference-request, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Consider nonlinear Schrodiner equation (NLS):

$$i\partial_t u + \Delta = \pm |u|^{p-1}u, u(x,0)=u_0 \in H^1(\mathbb R^d)$$
where $u:\mathbb R^{d+1} \to \mathbb C, u_0:\mathbb R^d \to \mathbb C,  1<p<\infty.$

We put $$E(u(t))= \frac{1}{2} \int_{\mathbb R^d} |\nabla u (x,t)|^2 dx \pm \frac{1}{p+1} \int_{\mathbb R^d} |u(x,t)|^{p+1} dx.$$

> My Question: How to show $E(u(t))= E(u(0))$ for all $t\in \mathbb R$? References is also OK, if I can found the solution of this fact in it.

Motivation: I am trying to following equation (3) in [the lecture note](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~vedranso/Concentration_Compactness.pdf),see also exercise 1 in the same note.

Answer (score 2):

It suffices to show that $$\frac d{dt} E(u(t)) = 0.$$

Start by moving the time derivative inside the integrals, which gives (using the product and chain rules)

$$\frac d{dt} E(u(t)) = {\rm Re}\int \nabla \partial_t u \cdot \nabla \bar u \pm {\rm Re}\int|u|^{p-1}\bar u \ \partial_t u$$

Assuming some kind of decay condition at infinity we can integrate by parts in the first integral to get $-{\rm Re}\int\partial_t u \ \Delta \bar u$, so substituting $\partial_t u$ using the evolution equation we get

$$\begin{align}\frac d{dt} E(u(t))  &= {\rm Re}\int (i \Delta u \mp i |u|^{p-1} u)( -\Delta \bar u\pm |u|^{p-1}\bar u)\\
&= {\rm Re}\left[\int i|\Delta u|^2 - \int i|u|^{2(p-1)}u \bar u\ \pm\int i\left(\Delta u |u|^{p-1}\bar u +\Delta \bar u |u|^{p-1}u\right)\right].
\end{align}$$

All three integrals here are purely imaginary and thus their real parts vanish, so we have the desired result.

Comment: @AC: Thanks: Why $E(u(t))$ is differentiable? How you are getting real part of the integral?  See [this also](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1908317/how-to-show-nls-conserves-the-energy)

Comment: @abcd: if $f(x,t)$ is differentiable then $d/dt \int f(x,t) dx = \int \partial_t f(x,t) dx$ so long as $f$ isn't too wild - for the exact condition you need to use something like the dominated convergence theorem, but a decay condition at infinity should suffice.The $\text{Re}$ is coming from the product rule: $d(f \bar f) = df \bar f + f d \bar f = 2 \text{Re} (\bar f df)$.

Comment: @AC:Thanks:I have some notional confusion.


For $z\in \mathbb C,$ we have $|z|^2= z\bar{z}$ (complex multiplication), and $z+\bar{z}= 2 \text{Re}(z)$
But $\nabla u(x) = (\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}u(x),...,\frac{\partial}{\partial x_n}u(x) ), x=(x_1,...,x_n)$ and $|\nabla u(x)|^2= (\partial_{x_1} u)^2+...+(\partial_{x_n} u)^2$. And so $\frac{d}{dt}|\nabla u(x,t)|^2= 2 ((\partial_{x_1} u)\partial_{x_1}\partial_t(u)+....+(\partial_{x_n} u)\partial_{x_n}\partial_t(u) )$.

Comment: But I am curious to know how to get directly: $\frac{d}{dt} |\nabla u(x,t)|^2= \text{Re} ( \nabla \partial_t u \cdot \nabla \bar{u} )$ What is $\cdot$ means? I just want to know, these are standard notations to use?

Comment: @abcd: $\cdot$ is the dot product. You need to be careful, when $u$ is complex valued $|\nabla u|^2 = \nabla u \cdot \nabla \bar u = \partial_{x_1} u \partial_{x_1} \bar u + \cdots$. If you include these conjugates then your expression matches up with $\text{Re} \nabla \partial_t u \cdot \nabla \bar u$.